# How to store text file into 2d int array

Tags: java, io, command-line-arguments, iostream

I have two files formatted as follows below where the first int needs to be stored somewhere and the second line and down are going to be stored into a 2d array. The first number, in this case, 4, will indicate the size as int [][] array = new int [2*4][4]; The 4, however, should not be part of the array and should be discarded. The file paths will be provided to the program via the command line. I haven't been able to find any could that could perform this function.

```
4
7 5 6 4
5 4 6 7
4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7
```

Comment: What specific problem is preventing you from progressing?

Comment: I have no code that performs the function I'm looking for, nothing that I've attempted or found here has worked for this specific purpose.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer forum, not a free code-writing service.  But if you have some code that you've tried and are having trouble with, please add it to your question and we'll be happy to help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used java 7 API to read file into a list.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        int[][] arr = null;
        String path = args[0];
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        for (int i=0; i<lines.size() ; i++) {
            String[] aStr = lines.get(i).split("\\s+");
            if(aStr.length==1) {    
                int size = Integer.valueOf(aStr[0]);
                System.out.println("Size of array "+size);
                arr = new int[size][size];
                populateArr(arr, lines.subList(i+1, i+size+1));
                print(arr);
                i = i+size;
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void populateArr(int[][] arr, List<String> list) {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            String[] values = list.get(i).split("\\s+");
            for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void print(int[][] arr) {
        System.out.println("***********PRINT***********");
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
}
```

Input (File location)
file content is as below

```
4
7 5 6 4
5 4 6 7
4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output from java program

```
Size of array 4
***********PRINT***********
7 5 6 4 
5 4 6 7 
4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 
Size of array 3
***********PRINT***********
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```